# Solving quartic equation with square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, radicals, quadratic-forms

I am trying to solve the following equation for $d_2$ (from this paper [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16022174/)):

$$ \frac{c{\sqrt{(d_1+d_2)}}-\sqrt{d_1}z_1 -( \alpha)(d_2)\big(p_1(1-p_1)\big)^{1/2}}{\sqrt{d_2}}= -z_{\beta}$$

I've tried various manipulations, moving $\sqrt{d_2}$ to the right hand side, then squaring, for example, but the hold up is always the $\sqrt{(d_1+d_2)}$ term.

My question is:

How do they solve for $d_2$?

Thank you!

Edit: they assume that rather than equality, there is an inequality, and they can make the denominator larger to satisfy it, then it becomes a quadratic of $d_2$.

$$ \frac{c{\sqrt{(d_1+d_2)}}-\sqrt{d_1}z_1 -( \alpha)(d_2)\big(p_1(1-p_1)\big)^{1/2}}{\sqrt{d_2}} \leq  -z_{\beta}$$

$$ \frac{c{\sqrt{(d_1+d_2)}}-\sqrt{d_1}z_1 -( \alpha)(d_2)\big(p_1(1-p_1)\big)^{1/2}}{\sqrt{d1+d_2}} =  -z_{\beta}$$

Comment: For practical purposes, why not just solve numerically? That is, given values for the other variables, use an algorithm to try different values of $d_2$ until you find one that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*} \frac{c{\sqrt{(d_1+d_2)}}-\sqrt{d_1}z_1 -( \alpha)(d_2)\big(p_1(1-p_1)\big)^{1/2}}{\sqrt{d_2}} &= -z_{\beta} \
\\
\\
c{\sqrt{(d_1+d_2)}}-\sqrt{d_1}z_1 -( \alpha)(d_2)\big(p_1(1-p_1)\big)^{1/2} &= -z_{\beta}\sqrt{d_2} \
\\
\\
c{\sqrt{(d_1+d_2)}} &= -z_{\beta}\sqrt{d_2} +\sqrt{d_1}z_1 +( \alpha)(d_2)\big(p_1(1-p_1)\big)^{1/2}  \
\\
\\
c^2(d_1+d_2) &= \left[-z_{\beta}\sqrt{d_2} +\sqrt{d_1}z_1 +( \alpha)(d_2)\big(p_1(1-p_1)\big)^{1/2}\right]^2  \
\\
\end{align*}$$

Eliminates the $\sqrt{(d_1+d_2)}$ term.

Comment: Thanks! However, when I square the right hand side, this becomes a function of the square root of $d_2$ and the square of $d_2$.  Is it possible to solve for $d_2$ with this approach?

Comment: $$c^2(d_1+d_2) = z_\beta^2 d_2 + 2z_\beta\sqrt{d_2}z_1\sqrt{d1}-2z_\beta \sqrt{d_2} \alpha d_2 (p(1-p))^{1/2} + z_1^2d_1 + 2z_1 \sqrt{d_1} \alpha d_2 (p(1-p))^{1/2} + \alpha^2 d_2^2(p(1-p))$$

Comment: Maybe substitute $d_2 = x^2$ and then you have a quartic in x.  The quartic equation solution is big and messy.  If trying to plug in actual numbers into the quartic equation solution, computers will run into numerical problems due to finite precision.

Comment: But I guess my question is: is it possible to solve the quartic?  I see what you're saying about plugging in $d_2 = x^2$.  Then it becomes a polynomial of degree 4.  I'm just curious if there's a closed-form solution, although I know numerical methods are possible.

Comment: Given that there is nothing special about the coefficients of the quartic polynomial, then the only closed form solution is given by the quartic equation solution - which is multiple steps and messy, but still closed.